# Get PID from ShellExecuteExA in win8

Tags: c++, windows-8

I need to open file in default application in win8 and get it's process id. I'm using following code:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFOA  ShExecInfo;
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = filePath.c_str();
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteExA(&ShExecInfo); 
int pid = GetProcessId(ShExecInfo.hProcess);
```

And it works fine. However, when i'm trying to open file in Metro - style apps, like Microsoft PDF viewer, file is opened OK, but pid is 0. How can i get pid of an metro-style application?

Comment: `0` most probably means failure. Did you try to call `GetLastError()`? The process handle may not have the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access right.

Comment: will probably not change anything but try setting verb to `L"open"`

Comment: XY question, all process interop with a "Metro" style app is *verboten* and actively blocked.  Getting 0 is just a helpful way to get you to give up early on something you can never make work anyway.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf good idea, wrong signature. The OP is using `ShellExecuteExA` not `ShellExecuteExW` like they should be.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why did they do that? I used [ModernMix](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/) for a time to get those Metro apps in windows, but it couldn't deal with the secondary full-screen dialog they sometime display. I can't think of any advantage?

Comment: @kban use Sumatra or Foxit PDF viewers.

Comment: Because Apple makes a *lot* of money with their store, selling programs that run on devices without a virus scanner.  Microsoft wants some of that too.

Comment: Yes, there is GetLastError() check  after ShellExecuteExA in my code, and the result is 0. If I understood right, it's not possible to get pid of an metro application? If so, how can I know when the file opened in metro application is closed?

Comment: The process id of a Store app is not stable. It can change if the app gets suspended, then terminated, then resumed. (This is more likely to happen on low memory machines.) What do you intend to do with the process id anyway?

Comment: @Hans: if that's the case they might want to [be a bit more careful about what they let in](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/151b00d7-b39c-4624-b859-764653586ca6).  :-)